# python what's a good way to assign multiple variables from CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x

My code has to read values from a CSV file and assign them to variables.

Each line SHOULD contain 7 values, although sometimes data may not be present, in which case I need to use a placeholder.
Lines from the CSV could look like this:

```
Alice White,https://www.link.to.website.com,BIO AB0629,Present,2021-03-27,JPMorgan,MD,2021-03-26
Bob Black,https://www.link.to.other.website.com,,Present,,Not Available,,2021-03-26
```

So far I have a long piece of code (with lots of TRY blocks) which I'd like to improve. How can it be done better?

```
with open(CANDIDATE_FILE) as f:
    candidates = [line for line in f]
    
for i, line in enumerate(candidates):
    line = line.rstrip()
    candidate = line.split(',')
    
    # here's the very long TRY/EXCEPT code
     candidate_name = candidate[0]
     try:
         candidate_linkedin = candidate[1]
     except:
         candidate_linkedin = "???"  # note placeholder values are not always the same
     try:
         candidate_bio_number = candidate[2]
     except:
         candidate_bio_number = "00000" 
     try:
         candidate_status = candidate[3]
     except:
         candidate_status = "Not Available"        
     # ...and the list continues in a similar way for all values
```

I feel this code (40 lines) is too long and looks messy. What's best practice in this case?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input data? You can use list comprehension with if and else statements, something like: `["???" if len(cell) == 0 else cell for cell in line.split(',')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just use candidate as the list itself. You can reference each of them separately using index.

Here's a quick list comprehension way to do it. This also addresses the default values.

```
with open('abc.txt', 'r') as f:
    default = ['???','0000','Not Available','???','0000','Not Available','???','0000']
    for line in f:
        temp = [c if c else '???' for c in line.strip().split(',')]
        t = len(temp)
        candidate = [temp[i] if ((i < t) and (temp[i] != '???')) else default[i] for i in range(8)]
        for c in candidate: print (c)
```

The input for the file are:

```
Alice White,https://www.link.to.website.com,BIO AB0629,Present,2021-03-27,JPMorgan,MD,2021-03-26
Bob Black,https://www.link.to.other.website.com,,Present,,Not Available,,2021-03-26
Susan White,https://www.link.to.website.com,BIO SW0644,Present
Greg Black
```

Note that the file is varying length and also does not have all 8 fields comma separated. The solution will address for all conditions.

For each line read, I have printed the values using `for c in candidate: print (c)`. The output of this is:

```
Alice White
https://www.link.to.website.com
BIO AB0629
Present
2021-03-27
JPMorgan
MD
2021-03-26
Bob Black
https://www.link.to.other.website.com
Not Available
Present
0000
Not Available
???
2021-03-26
Susan White
https://www.link.to.website.com
BIO SW0644
Present
0000
Not Available
???
0000
Greg Black
0000
Not Available
???
0000
Not Available
???
0000
```

You can decide to change the default values in the list to meet your needs.

On the other hand if your file is always going to have the 8 values in csv format, then you can reduce the code to the following:

```
with open('abc.txt', 'r') as f:
    default = ['???','0000','Not Available','???','0000','Not Available','???','0000']

    for line in f:
        candidate = [c if c else default[i] for i,c in enumerate(line.strip().split(','))]

        for c in candidate: print (c)
```

The output of this file will be:

```
Alice White,https://www.link.to.website.com,BIO AB0629,Present,2021-03-27,JPMorgan,MD,2021-03-26
Bob Black,https://www.link.to.other.website.com,,Present,,Not Available,,2021-03-26
Susan White,https://www.link.to.website.com,BIO SW0644,Present,,,,
Greg Black,,,,,,,
```

Output:

```
Alice White
https://www.link.to.website.com
BIO AB0629
Present
2021-03-27
JPMorgan
MD
2021-03-26
Bob Black
https://www.link.to.other.website.com
Not Available
Present
0000
Not Available
???
2021-03-26
Susan White
https://www.link.to.website.com
BIO SW0644
Present
0000
Not Available
???
0000
Greg Black
0000
Not Available
???
0000
Not Available
???
0000
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to clarify (fixed it now) that default values are not always "???" as my initial example had suggested. Also, code is quite long so using variable names rather that indexes helps avoiding confusion.

Comment: @Patrick, updated the code to take care of the default values. Also took care of varying length file and varying number of parameters sent in the file. If the file is constant with 7 values sent, then some of the code is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does a great job.

**EDIT:** with default values

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict_defaults = {
    0: '???', 1: 'val', 2: '++', 3: '--', 
    4: 'hello', 5: 'world', 6: 'foo'}

with open(CANDIDATE_FILE, 'r') as csv:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in csv]
df = pd.Series(lines).str.split(',', expand=True)

df[df==''] = np.nan
df = df.fillna(dict_defaults)
```

This gives:

```
             0                                      1           2        3           4              5    6           7
0  Alice White        https://www.link.to.website.com  BIO AB0629  Present  2021-03-27       JPMorgan   MD  2021-03-26
1    Bob Black  https://www.link.to.other.website.com          ++  Present       hello  Not Available  foo  2021-03-26
```

Column names can be assigned easily.

Answer (score 0):

instead of storing them as individual items, you could store them in a dict and use zip to pair the fields and values then fill in the missing fields

```py
data = """1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2
1,2,3,4,5,6
"""

fields = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'var6', 'var7']
default = ['???', 'val', '++', '--', 'hello', 'world', 'foo']
for line in data.splitlines():
    values = line.split(',')
    mapped_data = dict(pair for pair in zip(fields, values))
    for index, field in enumerate(fields):
        if field not in mapped_data:
            mapped_data[field] = default[index]
    print(mapped_data)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'var1': '1', 'var2': '2', 'var3': '3', 'var4': '4', 'var5': 'hello', 'var6': 'world', 'var7': 'foo'}
{'var1': '1', 'var2': '2', 'var3': '3', 'var4': '4', 'var5': '5', 'var6': '6', 'var7': '7'}
{'var1': '1', 'var2': '2', 'var3': '++', 'var4': '--', 'var5': 'hello', 'var6': 'world', 'var7': 'foo'}
{'var1': '1', 'var2': '2', 'var3': '3', 'var4': '4', 'var5': '5', 'var6': '6', 'var7': 'foo'}
```

you can then just access the data like `mapped_data['var4']`

a slightly updated version which is a bit cleaner is to create the dict first with all the default values, then replace those values you got from the file.

```py
data = """1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2
1,2,3,4,5,6
"""

fields = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'var6', 'var7']
defaults = ['???', 'val', '++', '--', 'hello', 'world', 'foo']
default_data = dict(zip(fields, defaults))
for line in data.splitlines():
    values = line.split(',')
    data = dict(zip(fields, defaults))
    mapped_data = dict(zip(fields, values))
    data.update(mapped_data)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks. However I should have made clearer that default values are not always the same. I've updated the code above to clarify that. Can you solution be flexed to accommodate that?

Comment: Sure, so i have updated, by adding  list of default values, then I can then use the default value for that field to fill in the dict